# Resolving name of localized folders returned by JFileChooser in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, jfilechooser

In Mac OS, certain folders like "`Desktop`" or "`Applications`" are localized, so that in the Finder they are named for example "`Schreibtisch`" and "`Programme`" in German. This seems to lead to problems with the `JFileChooser in Java`.

When I set up a `JFileChooser` to allow only the selection of directories via the `setFileSelectionMode` method and the user selects "`Schreibtisch`", the path I receive back from the dialog is `*/Users/username/Schreibtisch*`. Obviously this folder does not exists, because it is the localized name of `*/Users/username/Desktop*`.

`File.exists()` or `File.isDirectory()` both return false and getCanonicalPath() does not resolve the localization. Is there any way of retrieving the "physical" path from a localized one?

Strangely, when the user selects a sub folder of "`Schreibtisch`", eg `*/Users/username/Schreibtisch/images*`, the returned path is `*/Users/username/Desktop/images*`, which is correct.

Comment: I just realized that this only happens when I call showDialog(), not when I use showOpenDialog(). I would still like to know how I can resolve the path as described above.